# How to test if two populations are different with the x axis a time variable

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, pearson-r

I have two populations: Class `A` and Class `B`.  Both populations have two variables: `percent_correct` (i.e. number right answers / total answers) and `week`.  I have graph comparing the two populations with the `percent_correct` on the y-axis measured over `time` (x-axis measured in weeks).

The two populations have similar trends. However, I would like to do a statistical test to see if they are statistically similar.  What test do I use? I'm confused as I'm looking at the similarities over time and not at one fixed point.

Should I use the $r$ correlation?  Or what do you advise?

Also the variable `percent_correct` (y-axis) is independent of the variable `week` (x-axis).

Sample data looks like this:

```
Class percent_correct date;  
A        10%          04/01/2013  
B        50%          04/01/2013  
A        5%           04/10/2013  
B        3%           04/10/2013  
A        11%          04/20/2013  
B        14%          04/22/2013  
A        0%           04/28/2013  
B        2%           04/27/2013
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do you have *samples* or *populations*. How many time periods do you have? What do you mean by "statistically similar"?

Comment: Thank you for your questions.  I have two different populations and approximately 50 time periods, though it varies depending on which populations I am comparing.   In terms of "statistically similar"  I can visually see that the trends for the two populations (Class A and Class B) are similar. However I would like to quantify it and see how closely correlated the two groups really are.

Comment: I am not expert on this, but I added the timeseries tag so that people who are expert will see it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite specific test you can use. It is called the "pairwise t-test"/"paired t-test" or its equivalent if your data is not normally distributed.

That test compares two by two all the points. In this case you need to compare the pairwise datapoints belonging to the same week.
This test tells you if overall there are differences between your populations, controling for the week variable.

Comment: The applicability of this answer to the question looks doubtful. The example in the question shows there aren't uniquely defined pairs of points: it looks like there may be zero, one, or more of each kind of value in any given week, and the two weekly counts don't even have to be the same.